# 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ScriptForWebTaggingUI' is null or not an object

Tags: sharepoint-2010

This is regarding SharePoint 2010 Search Refiners for people search.

When I click on `Show More` option in Job Title or Building name Refiner, it doesn't expand and all I see is javascript error popping in IE status bar.

```
'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ScriptForWebTaggingUI' is null or not an object
```

On further investigation, I noticed that this happens when search results count is above 50. For anything below 50 results, the refiners work absolutely fine. Moreover, the issue is present with one site collection, rest seem to be working fine.

I have tried to reproduce issue under broken site collection using new enterprise search centre (as sub site) but still no luck.